# What happens if terraform local-exec destroy provisioner fails?

Tags: terraform, cloud, devops, terraform-provider-aws

Let's say I have written a terraform local-exec provisioner with when = destroy condition, what will happen if that destroy time provisioner fails. Will the resource be deleted or resource will be marked as tainted or some other behaviour ?

Comment: You can always take a look at the source code.

Answer (score 0):

Terraform runs destroy-time provisioners before destroying the resource instance they are attached to.

If any provisioner fails, `terraform apply` will abort with an error message but Terraform does not keep any record of the failure in the persistent state. Creating a new plan after the failure will (as long as the situation hasn't otherwise changed) again plan to destroy the object and try again to run the destroy-time provisioners before destroying it.

---

To answer this question I referred to [the current source code for the resource destroy action](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/blob/f79e912a81644201e807fa37e68d06b27e7c86c3/internal/terraform/node_resource_destroy.go#L196-L216), which I'll reproduce here for future reference:

```
    // Run destroy provisioners if not tainted
    if state.Status != states.ObjectTainted {
        applyProvisionersDiags := n.evalApplyProvisioners(ctx, state, false, configs.ProvisionerWhenDestroy)
        diags = diags.Append(applyProvisionersDiags)
        // keep the diags separate from the main set until we handle the cleanup

        if diags.HasErrors() {
            // If we have a provisioning error, then we just call
            // the post-apply hook now.
            diags = diags.Append(n.postApplyHook(ctx, state, diags.Err()))
            return diags
        }
    }

    // Managed resources need to be destroyed, while data sources
    // are only removed from state.
    // we pass a nil configuration to apply because we are destroying
    s, _, d := n.apply(ctx, state, changeApply, nil, false)
    state, diags = s, diags.Append(d)
    // we don't return immediately here on error, so that the state can be
    // finalized
```